# PTIJ: Why does G-d want to give us The Wizard of Oz?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Psalmist (I think its #29) said:

> ה' עוז לעמו יתן
>
> G-d will give us Oz

What's the purpose to giving us The Wizard of Oz? I thought we are supposed to kill wizards, no? Is that the whole point of giving him to us - so we can kill him?

Even if this is meant to be an exception, The Wizard of Oz is useful only for granted three things - a heart, a brain, and courage. I thought that these things are granted by G-d, not from wizards. As a matter of fact, we pray for each of these every day, and we are asking G-d, himself to grant these to us. Should we praying to the Great Wizard instead?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: It's in 29. Or was that the joke?

Comment: @DonielF Thanks. I edited. The joke is that you thought that it was a joke.

Answer (score 4):

G-d knew that Jewish cuisine would develop in a somewhat unhealthy manner, so he gave us the Wizard of Oz to carry out heart bypasses and other cardiac procedures.

As we read in [Tehillim 84:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.84.6?lang=bi):

> אשרי אדם עוז לו בך מסילות בלבבם
>
> Happy is the person who has Oz; you will have pathways in your heart.